# Swift 3 and MacOS: how to load file directly from disk

Tags: command-line-interface, swift3, ciimage

I'm trying to come up with a simple command-line macOS application which will blur an input image with Core Image and save it somewhere on disk like so:

```
./my-binary /absolute/path/input.jpg /absolute/path/output.jpg
```

How do I load an image from absolute path into `CIImage`?

I have the following code:

```
let imageURL = Bundle.main.pathForImageResource("/absolute/path/input.jpg")
let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL)
```

However the `imageURL` holds `nil` after executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the Bundle you need to use the paths you are giving to your command line app. For this, use `CommandLine.Arguments`.

Simple example:

```
import Foundation
import CoreImage

let args = CommandLine.arguments

if args.count > 2 {
    let inputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: args[1])
    let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: args[2])
    if let inputImage = CIImage(contentsOf: inputURL) {
        // use the CIImage here
        // save the modified image to outputURL
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
} else {
    fputs("Error - Not enough arguments\n", stderr)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: Use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` instead of `0` and `1`, and  print error messages to stderr instead of stdout for command-line tools.

Comment: @MartinR Good idea. Done.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.